# useForm value not setting state react

Tags: reactjs

I have a antd form where I get those values with useForm. But I not able to set my state with values from the form.

Code:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});

  const onFinish = () => {
        console.log("form", form.getFieldValue());
    setUserDetails(form.getFieldValue());
  };

<Form
            form={form}
            name="payment"
            initialValues={
              {
                //   remember: true,
              }
            }
            layout="vertical"
            onFinish={onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            autoComplete="off"
          >
            <div>
              <Form.Item
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                rules={[
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input your email!",
                  },
                  {
                    type: "email",
                  },
                ]}
              >
                <Input placeholder="Enter Your Email" className="text-left" />
              </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Console logging `form.getFieldValue()` is returning correct data, but couldn't set the same data to state ( `setUserDetails(form.getFieldValue());` )

Comment: How do you check that `userDetails` has updated or not?

Comment: Check two way, useEffect and also my api wasn't getting data

Comment: put `console.log(userDetails)` in the body of your component and check the result after submitting the form

Comment: i've tried `console.log(userDetails)`  inside the function body, the state is updating correctly. see this https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-mopsa-u4p8w?file=/src/App.js